# how to identify the commit in github

Tags: git, github

Myself and my friend is working in a same project sharing the same github repository. In order to reveal both of our identities, my friend suggested & masked his identity matching mine by issuing the commands in his local PC.

```
$ git config --global user.name "XYZ"
$ git config --global user.email "xyz@example.com"
```

At the end of day when I took the git log for that application, I can see all the commits made by both of us, but all the commits bear the same username & email address.

How do I identify the commits made by me from the commits made by my friend?

Comment: you can grep you history for `git commit` command. `git reflog` also could be useful

Answer (score 0):

You can't know the author of the commit, if both of you use the same author information. It should be unique to each user, that's what it is for.

Comment: Downvoter care to explain? The OP states that both users have set the same username and email address, thus the commits cannot be allotted to individual users.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the distributed nature of `git` the server (be it GitHub or something else) has to accept the identities presented in commit messages it receives.  If you want to be able to authenticate these identities, you need to cryptographically sign your commits using something like GPG.  [This page](https://phreaknerd.wordpress.com/2012/02/09/signing-git-commits-with-your-gpg-key/) discusses how to do it.  Assuming you already have GPG configured, you just need to add `-S` to your commit command line:

```
git commit -S -m "this is a test"
```

And you can verify commit identities using "git log --show-signature", which will get you output like this:

```
commit dadcd364efe5e2751b9ee4ef9a3e9b1b4e2ba4f9
gpg: Signature made Wed Jul 24 08:14:44 2013 EDT
gpg:                using RSA key 0x042DF6CF74E4B84C
gpg: Good signature from "Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@oddbit.com>" [ultimate]
Author: Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@oddbit.com>
Date:   Wed Jul 24 08:14:38 2013 -0400

    removed things
```

...although this requires you to correctly manage your GPG web-of-trust in order to believe the signature.

Answer (score 0):

Note the `git log --show-signature` changes in Git 2.10 (Q3 2016) from

```
commit 2376d31
merged tag 'v2.9.3'
gpg: Signature made Fri 12 Aug 2016 09:17:59 AM PDT using RSA key ID 96AFE6CB <=====
gpg: Good signature from "Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>"
gpg:                 aka "Junio C Hamano <jch@google.com>"
gpg:                 aka "Junio C Hamano <junio@pobox.com>"
Merge: 2807cd7 e0c1cea
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
Date:   Fri Aug 12 10:02:18 2016 -0700
```

to

```
commit 2376d31
merged tag 'v2.9.3'
gpg: Signature made Fri 12 Aug 2016 09:17:59 AM PDT
gpg:                using RSA key B0B5E88696AFE6CB           <=======================
gpg: Good signature from "Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>"
gpg:                 aka "Junio C Hamano <jch@google.com>"
gpg:                 aka "Junio C Hamano <junio@pobox.com>"
Merge: 2807cd7 e0c1cea
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
Date:   Fri Aug 12 10:02:18 2016 -0700
```

See [commit b624a3e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b624a3e67f498cb41f704c9bd28e7d53076611c8) (16 Aug 2016) by [Linus Torvalds (`torvalds`)](https://github.com/torvalds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 83d9eb0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/83d9eb0ad85eeb88cb1dce88cf86458c6d3e57f1), 19 Aug 2016)</sup>

> ### `gpg-interface`: prefer "long" key format output when verifying pgp signatures
>
> Yes, gpg2 already uses the long format by default, but most distributions seem to still have "gpg" be the older 1.x version due to compatibility reasons.  And older versions of gpg only show the 32-bit short ID, which is quite insecure.
>
> This doesn't actually matter for the *verification* itself: if the
>   verification passes, the pgp signature is good.
>   **But if you don't actually have the key yet, and want to fetch it, or you want to check exactly which key was used for verification and want to check it, we should specify the key with more precision**.
>
> In fact, we should preferentially specify the whole key fingerprint, but
>   gpg doesn't actually support that.  Which is really quite sad.
>
> **Showing the "long" format improves things to at least show 64 bits of
>   the fingerprint.  That's a lot better, even if it's not perfect**.